# Targeting empty classes

Tags: css

I'd like to apply the `green` `background` to *paragraphs* with *classes* and the `red` one to all the others. I've made it half way through but still struggling with empty *classes* `class=""`:

```css
p {background:green}

#test p:not([class]) {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>This should be red</p>
  <p class="abc">This should be green</p>
  <p class="newname">This should be green</p>
  <p class="">This should be red</p>
  <p class="anothername">This should be green</p>
  <p>This should be red</p>
  <p class="">This should be red</p>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0eLsxdz/)

Anyone knows a way?

Comment: yep. understood. If possible, will include snippet in my questions in feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can target a `p` with an empty class like this...

```
p[class=""] {
    ...
}
```

```css
body {
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  background: green
}

#test p:not([class]),
#test p[class=""] {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>This should be red</p>
  <p class="abc">This should be green</p>
  <p class="newname">This should be green</p>
  <p class="">This should be red</p>
  <p class="anothername">This should be green</p>
  <p>This should be red</p>
  <p class="">This should be red</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh...simple. How can i miss this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used #test p[class=""] i hope thats what you wanted.

```
body{
  font-weight:700;
}
p{background:green}

#test p:not([class]) {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
}

#test p[class=""]{
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
}
```